# Video uploading on Google drive via IOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

I just want to upload video on google drive, till now i able to download the content of text file and also the list of all text file by using DrEdit for Objective-C / iOS sample code.
It also gave a example of image uploading but this is also not helpful for me. So could you please guys share your idea or link or code snippet regarding this, will be appreciable. thanks in advance

Comment: What is DrEdit? Came across so many questions which said followed DrEdit guide/code. Cant find anything about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> just follow this link this is for uploading image.

i just edit the method

- (void)uploadPhoto:(UIImage*)image to -(void)uploadVideo: 
  [image upload sample](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-ios)

  ```
    -(void)uploadVideo{
      NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
      [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"'Quickstart Uploaded File ('EEEE MMMM d, YYYY h:mm a, zzz')"];

   GTLDriveFile *file = [GTLDriveFile object];
    file.title = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    file.descriptionProperty = @"Uploaded from the Google Drive iOS Quickstart";
    file.mimeType = @"video/quicktime";
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Test" ofType:@"Mov"];

    NSError *error = nil;
     NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath options:nil error:&error];
  // NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation((UIImage *)image);
     GTLUploadParameters *uploadParameters = [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:data MIMEType:file.mimeType];
      GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject:file
                                                 uploadParameters:uploadParameters];

    UIAlertView *waitIndicator = [self showWaitIndicator:@"Uploading to Google Drive"];

     [self.driveService executeQuery:query
            completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                GTLDriveFile *insertedFile, NSError *error) {
                [waitIndicator dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
                if (error == nil)
                {
                    NSLog(@"File ID: %@", insertedFile.identifier);
                    [self showAlert:@"Google Drive" message:@"File saved!"];
                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
                    [self showAlert:@"Google Drive" message:@"Sorry, an error occurred!"];
                }
            }];


  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple implementation using Swift 2.2 & Google API 3 to upload a video.

You just need to provide a path for where the video is located. Or, you can replace it with a URL and save yourself a step in the function.

```
func uploadVideo(videoPath: String) {
    let file = GTLDriveFile()
    file.name = "video.mov"
    file.descriptionProperty = "Video description"
    file.mimeType = "video/quicktime"

    let videoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: videoPath)
    let uploadParameters = GTLUploadParameters(fileURL: videoURL, MIMEType: file.mimeType)
    let query = GTLQueryDrive.queryForFilesCreateWithObject(file, uploadParameters: uploadParameters)

    service.executeQuery(query) { (ticket, insertedObject, error) in
        if error == nil {
            print(ticket)
        } else {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```